# How to collect data after Flux.subscribe to send it as a json array?

Tags: java, spring, reactor

This is an example that I made it, what should I do to get the treated data to send the result list as a WS json response ?

```
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public List<String> tryFlux(@QueryParam("names") List<String> names) {
         String[] array = new String[names.size()];
         Flux.fromIterable(asList(names.toArray(array))).
                 doOnNext(this::executeService).doOnError(ex -> handleError(ex, names)).retry(1).subscribe();
         return ??; //Need help here
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap already resolved values with Mono to return JSON data.

```
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Mono<JSONResponseObject> tryFlux(@QueryParam("names") List<String> names) {
     String[] array = new String[names.size()];
     Flux.fromIterable(asList(names.toArray(array))).
             doOnNext(this::executeService).doOnError(ex -> handleError(ex, names)).retry(1).subscribe();
     return Mono.just(jsonResponseObject); //Need help here
  }
```